# Array value overridding on same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/fgazs/4/

Fiddle for my code

I want the array value to be fetched if the select box contains the class name **"customCheckEnabled"** and on the basis on the selected index corresponding message should get display, For say if there are 3 select boxes with class name **"customCheckEnabled"** then 3 message should be displays one after another.Currently in my code same value is getting overridden.

There are different array for different select boxes.
Suppose there are 4 select box with class name **"customCheckEnabled"**  then there will be 4 array.

Comment: Strive to always post a minimal piece of code that highlights the problem instead of posting an external link.

Comment: @Jack External link contains a minimal problem. Have u checked that link. It is easy to check in link rathr than posting code

Comment: The time it takes to ask a question is inversely correlated to the quality of answers, for a big enough question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've shortened your code to something that I think you want to achieve:

```
$(function() {
    var messages = {
        'testName': ['Custom message for label 1', 'Custom message for label 2'],
        'testName1': ['Custom message for label 11', 'Custom message for label 22'],
        'testName2': ['Custom message for label 111', 'Custom message for label 222']
    }

        $('.customCheckEnabled').change(function() {
            var msgList = messages[this.id] || [],
            msg = msgList[this.selectedIndex] || '';

            console.log('message = ' + msg);
        });
});
```

Comment: I want if there is select box with the class name "customCheckEnabled" it should show message for all the select message , For say 1st select box index is 1 and 2nd select box index is 2 then both the message should come

Comment: @KunalVashist That's easy enough ... inside the `change()` you do another `$('.customCheckEnabled').each(function() { ... });` and put my code in there.

Comment: @KunalVashist okay, if the answer helped in solving your problem mark it as accepted, otherwise answer it yourself and do likewise :)